# In mongodb collection name "testslist" not works?

Tags: node.js, express, collections, mongodb-query

I am using the collection name testslist then it not work and when i change the name of collection it works.

Comment: Works fine even with "testsList" collection name. Please elaborate on your issue.

Comment: In my code what happen if i use "testList" the find() query give null response. if i change name of collection it works fine ?

Comment: I don't think it could create any issue. Can you post in your code for which it's not working and for code which it's working?